# JOptionPane.showmessagedialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So i have to write a DrawKwin.java which will print the letter K with little stars(*).
The user gives an integer parameter, if the parameter is less than 4 or more than 30 the program will terminate.
With the parameter, the program will create as many lines as the parameter trying to print the letter K.
For example if the user types the number 6 , the program will print 6 lines trying to create the letter K.The input will be from a input panel with  and the letter K will be printed in an output panel with joptionpane.showmessagedialog().

Here is the code without the output panel code:

```
       package Askisi_A1;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class DrawKwin {

public static void main(String[] L) {
    int line=Integer.parseInt(L[0]); // make L an  integer.


    if(line <= 4) 
    {
        System.out.println("Program end, wrong argument!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(line >= 30) 
    {
        System.out.println("Program end, wrong argument!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    do
    {

        int mid=line/2; // find the middle.
        int gap=0;     // 'gap' is for the gap between the stars .
        for(int i=0;i<line;i++)   //loop for the creation of letter K.
        {
            if(i==0) gap=mid;
            if(i<mid) // if it is before the middle of letter K, start printing stars and gaps but start with gap=middle and the decrease the number of gaps as you change lines.
            {

                System.out.print("*");
                for(int j=gap;j>0;j--)   // placement of gaps between the stars.
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println("*");
                gap--;
            }
            else if(i==mid && i!=0) // if it is in the middle of letter K, it will print only one star.
            {
                System.out.println("*");
                gap=1;
            }
            else // if it is past the middle section of letter K, it will continue printing gaps but now the gaps start from 0 and keep increasing at each line.
            {
                System.out.print("*");
                for(int j=0;j<gap;j++)  // placement of gaps between the stars.
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println("*");
                gap++;
            }

        }       


        line = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Give me a number ",4)); // input from input panel.
    }while(line>=4 && line<=30);


}
```

}

So , if the user gives the number 5 as an input, the output should be like this:

```
*  *
* *
*
* *
*  *
```

but i need this to be printed in an output panel with the help of joptionpane.showmessagedialog().
Can anybody help me please?
Sorry if my English is bad.
My deadline is in Monday.

Comment: Build a string \n is the new line characer.  Once you have built a string representing the K then use joptionpane.showmessagedialog() to display the built string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
do {

            int mid = line / 2; // find the middle.
            int gap = 0; // 'gap' is for the gap between the stars .
            for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) // loop for the creation of letter K.
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    gap = mid;
                if (i < mid) // if it is before the middle of letter K, start
                                // printing stars and gaps but start with
                                // gap=middle and the decrease the number of
                                // gaps as you change lines.
                {

                    output += "*";
                    for (int j = gap; j > 0; j--) // placement of gaps between
                                                    // the stars.
                    {
                        output += " ";
                    }
                    output += "*\n";
                    gap--;
                } else if (i == mid && i != 0) // if it is in the middle of
                                                // letter K, it will print only
                                                // one star.
                {
                    output += "*\n";
                    gap = 1;
                } else // if it is past the middle section of letter K, it will
                        // continue printing gaps but now the gaps start from 0
                        // and keep increasing at each line.
                {
                    output += "*";
                    for (int j = 0; j < gap; j++) // placement of gaps between
                                                    // the stars.
                    {
                        output += " ";
                    }
                    output += "*\n";
                    gap++;
                }

            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);

            line = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Give me a number ", 4)); // input from input panel.
            output = "";
        } while (line >= 4 && line <= 30);
```

Build your output string then showMessageDialog with output string.

Answer (score 0):

Create a String at the beginning, eg.

`String kLetter = ""`;

After every:

`System.out.print("*");`
add
`kLetter += "*";`

`System.out.print(" ");`
add
`kLetter += " ";`

`System.out.println("*");`
add
`kLetter += "*\n";`

then use

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(result, null);
```

to show result in dialog and remember to set result to empty string after you show it in dialog.

```
result = "";
```